Apple HomeKit ("Home" app) thinks I have a second camera, but I do not
I cannot enable recording on my Nest Camera, presumably because of my old Ring doorbell camera. There is no other camera in the Apple "Home" app whatsoever. I have removed the Nest camera, re-added it several times, but there's no change.
I cannot record due to only having the 50 GB iCloud plan (which only allows for a single camera.....which is what I have).
I've searched and searched online and the only way to remove an old camera is in the Home app....which I have already done.

